# DRF - serializer saves data but changes a date?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following output from `print(serializer.data)`:

```
[OrderedDict([('last_price', '62.63'), ('name', None), ('country', None), 
('sector', None), ('industry', None), ('ticker', 'VUSA'), 
('high_price', 62.7075), ('last_date_time', '2023-03-01T00:00:00+04:00')])]
```

When I go and look in the database(sql and postgres) the `last_date_time` field is: `2023-02-28 20:00:00`.

The create statement:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            print(serializer.data)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            return Response({"Status": "We should be done"})
```

The model:

```
class UsStockPriceModel(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)  # mainly for US stocks
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    high_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_date_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The Serializer:

```
class UsStockPriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_price = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)  # mainly for US stocks
    country = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    sector = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    industry = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

    # last_date_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = UsStockPriceModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_last_price(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None
        try:
            return float(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Valid integer is required')
```

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Different timezone. On the server it's in UTC it seems

Comment: @BojanKogoj I don't think that would be the issue, the `last_date_time` field after serialization is still `2023-03-01T00:00:00+04:00`?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres only stores dates in UTC interally, so that is what you are seeing.  The time you show is 4 hours before your posted time, and that time has `+04:00` as the offset.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

`2023-03-01T00:00:00+04:00` => `2023-02-28T20:00:00+00:00`